# cmd run automatically -> shell commands to view a sqlite database for android

Tags: android, sqlite, shell, cmd

I want to run a  'adb shell' -> to view a sqlite database for android.
I need to run commands automatically in a CMD file.
But I only can get access to the shell **#**,not to **sqlite3**

sqlite.cmd (file)

```
cd "C:\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools" 
adb shell
sqlite3 /data/data/ileran.game/databases/ilearn.db
```

If to run manually cmd console and write all this commands  -> it`s working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try executing shell as one command:

```
adb shell "sqlite3 /data/data/ileran.game/databases/ilearn.db"
```

**Update**

To start this and then take the input and redirect it to adb shell command you must use redirection operators. I'm not expert on Windows command shell, but try something like this:

```
0>adb shell "sqlite3 /data/data/ileran.game/databases/ilearn.db"
```

Read more about CMD redirection: http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: it`s running..,  but I cannot type any letters

Comment: Of course. After it completes the command file (shell.cmd) stops running.

Comment: oh.. what can I do.. to stay it 'OPEN' ?